# My onscroll event is not firing my java script function

Tags: javascript, html, function, onscroll

I'm trying to say in my code that if the user scrolls down 250px, I want the data-percent to go from 0% to 100% and this is done in "myFunction". I am still new to JS so I'm having trouble understanding why it's not working when I scroll past 250px. Any help would be much appreciated!

```js
var div = document.getElementById('div1');
window.onscroll = myFunction();

function myFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 250 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 250) {
    div.getAttribute('data-percent').value = "100%";
  } else {
    div.getAttribute('data-percent').value = "";
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="div1" class="skillbar clearfix " data-percent="100%">
  <div class="skillbar-title" style="background: #d35400;"><span>HTML5</span></div>
  <div class="skillbar-bar" style="background: #e67e22;"></div>
  <div class="skill-bar-percent">100%</div>
</div>
```

I expect the data-percent attribute to go from 0% to 100% when I scroll past 250px, and then back to 0% when I scroll back up.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the header to the top of the page so you could see it, and added some filler text to make it scroll, but the issue was that your code only called `myFunction` *as soon as the page loaded* - it wasn't doing anything else. You needed to change the call of `myFunction` into a *reference* to `myFunction` by removing the parentheses.

```js
var div = document.getElementById('div1');
window.onscroll = myFunction;

function myFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 250 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 250) {
    div.getAttribute('data-percent').value = "100%";
    div.querySelector(".skill-bar-percent").textContent = "100%";
  } else {
    div.getAttribute('data-percent').value = "";
    div.querySelector(".skill-bar-percent").textContent = "0%";
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="div1" class="skillbar clearfix " data-percent="100%" style="position: fixed; top: 0; background-color: white; display: block;">
  <div class="skillbar-title" style="background: #d35400;"><span>HTML5</span></div>
  <div class="skillbar-bar" style="background: #e67e22;"></div>
  <div class="skill-bar-percent">0%</div>
</div>

<br />
<br />

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In maximus facilisis dolor, mollis consequat justo vestibulum in. Pellentesque ac laoreet turpis. Duis eget sodales elit. In eget eros vitae nibh laoreet viverra. Fusce tincidunt tortor id metus iaculis, in pulvinar urna consectetur. Nunc in leo non lacus volutpat rhoncus. Vestibulum aliquet tortor quis vehicula tempor. Vivamus faucibus orci nec condimentum consequat. Vestibulum vestibulum venenatis tincidunt. Donec non velit nulla. Nunc tellus est, feugiat quis interdum luctus, rhoncus non nisi. Aenean sagittis sed nisl sit amet vehicula. Nulla maximus at lacus eget tristique. Curabitur dignissim ligula et massa rhoncus, id lobortis odio dignissim. Sed ut dolor ac libero lacinia laoreet nec eu urna. Morbi justo lectus, ultrices ac tellus ut, lobortis semper risus.</p>

<p>Phasellus tempor dignissim odio, sodales vulputate metus facilisis sit amet. Maecenas vestibulum dapibus ipsum, nec bibendum neque tempor eget. Nunc ullamcorper, libero et semper condimentum, nibh mi pretium nisi, a hendrerit elit nunc sed metus. Duis lacinia quis dui ut interdum. In efficitur vitae magna sit amet aliquam. Pellentesque quis ullamcorper lorem. Etiam id ullamcorper velit. Suspendisse id tristique ante, suscipit facilisis nisl. Ut ac orci quis augue ornare egestas a id eros. Curabitur dictum eros mauris, lacinia vulputate diam dignissim at. Curabitur venenatis posuere lorem, non maximus lectus lobortis in.</p>

<p>Praesent in finibus purus. Maecenas nec rutrum mi. Donec molestie rhoncus ex vel laoreet. Duis id leo sit amet nisi tristique porta non at enim. Suspendisse eu pharetra lorem. Nunc posuere odio nisl, id iaculis felis fringilla ut. Proin aliquam sapien quis tortor vestibulum interdum. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Pellentesque gravida bibendum urna, tincidunt venenatis ligula egestas vitae. Fusce accumsan ligula et diam porta, id finibus felis vulputate.</p>

<p>Ut eleifend venenatis quam, vel ultricies diam vestibulum sit amet. Vestibulum accumsan eu felis et dictum. Cras turpis tellus, sodales ut nibh accumsan, rutrum ullamcorper ligula. Donec mollis sem eros, vitae finibus dui ullamcorper vel. Mauris sodales diam ut dictum mattis. Nam varius nisi ac efficitur dapibus. Nam dignissim, dolor at suscipit dignissim, ipsum eros mollis risus, eget facilisis lacus dolor id nisl. Vivamus dictum rutrum neque, vel accumsan lacus vulputate in. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris vel tortor sed mi faucibus egestas non maximus enim. Suspendisse sed mi sagittis, imperdiet felis sed, tristique nisi. Proin porta nisi at pretium volutpat. Quisque nec nisl dictum, dignissim erat sit amet, vestibulum dui.</p>

<p>Curabitur vitae consectetur felis. In quis ligula metus. Nunc mauris ex, viverra in suscipit in, ultricies id lorem. Sed ac libero at velit iaculis placerat vitae in odio. Sed tortor dui, lobortis nec pretium ut, ullamcorper a dui. Praesent congue erat sed ultrices pretium. Nullam consequat orci at ex aliquet, vitae aliquet lorem suscipit. Maecenas nisi purus, semper eu lorem vel, elementum dapibus quam. Suspendisse potenti. Nulla augue enim, vulputate a fringilla eget, sollicitudin nec turpis. Aenean vitae pulvinar ante. Nam ex dui, gravida a nunc sed, tristique lacinia sapien. Sed auctor laoreet nisl, et maximus risus. Fusce finibus bibendum mauris. Ut cursus euismod eros non dapibus. Sed luctus eleifend lorem venenatis aliquam.</p>

<p>Morbi volutpat velit vitae est molestie, nec porttitor orci tempus. Suspendisse lorem arcu, elementum sit amet diam sit amet, pharetra laoreet metus. Integer posuere sapien porta, placerat odio lobortis, sollicitudin augue. Integer mattis arcu est, gravida porta justo ultrices a. Etiam egestas in ante at interdum. Cras sodales at lectus nec interdum. Donec ac posuere ligula, id dictum lectus. Nullam et elit non nunc convallis pulvinar. Pellentesque vitae pulvinar ex. Etiam a mattis risus, vitae gravida neque.</p>

<p>Nullam vestibulum nisl a faucibus sodales. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla iaculis gravida sem at aliquam. Vestibulum id enim suscipit, condimentum ipsum ut, egestas libero. Proin et leo ac eros hendrerit tincidunt dapibus ac urna. Integer tincidunt, est et faucibus malesuada, purus ligula ultricies velit, quis rutrum lacus quam non neque. Sed facilisis ipsum eget nisl consectetur sollicitudin. Donec sodales massa non quam ornare tristique. Suspendisse condimentum dui dolor, in ultrices leo laoreet non.</p>

<p>Morbi mattis, mi nec fringilla dignissim, nisl risus pharetra massa, in luctus sem magna at ex. Nullam aliquam ultricies dolor, eget maximus eros auctor sed. Suspendisse sodales orci a elementum dignissim. Maecenas vulputate pharetra nisl vel cursus. Sed sit amet molestie lacus. Etiam fringilla maximus velit at posuere. Vestibulum non metus non sapien molestie tempor. Ut tincidunt faucibus lectus. Aliquam scelerisque ligula vel dictum fermentum. Donec egestas velit consequat vehicula condimentum. Etiam semper rhoncus efficitur. Ut ut leo pretium nisi pharetra pharetra. Nullam elementum, metus at sollicitudin convallis, mauris eros sagittis justo, quis venenatis ante magna dignissim nisl. Donec sit amet tempus tellus, id ultrices quam. Aliquam dui dolor, placerat non metus ut, mattis imperdiet nisi. Maecenas ultrices felis lacus, ut mattis ipsum laoreet vitae.</p>

<p>Fusce commodo faucibus volutpat. Nulla tristique libero at mi ultricies, scelerisque lobortis risus accumsan. Vestibulum iaculis, est a blandit eleifend, lorem justo porttitor arcu, a feugiat arcu magna eget nulla. Mauris posuere massa vitae diam pretium placerat nec ut ex. Ut porttitor nisi sit amet felis eleifend, non fermentum nibh placerat. In molestie mi a mi rutrum tempus. Praesent fringilla semper mi, at accumsan lorem lobortis euismod.</p>

<p>Fusce fermentum interdum leo non auctor. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Pellentesque lectus ante, vehicula ac blandit dictum, pulvinar non tortor. Ut faucibus erat luctus, convallis magna non, ornare dolor. Sed dictum, nunc non iaculis pharetra, mi nisl pretium libero, at tincidunt massa felis eu mauris. Maecenas sit amet lorem non enim finibus posuere. Ut pulvinar aliquam convallis. Maecenas eu purus nec tortor bibendum maximus in quis enim. Fusce vehicula leo non felis posuere aliquet. Nam aliquet mauris nec felis dictum, non semper diam efficitur. Duis blandit euismod vestibulum. Nulla quis leo venenatis, volutpat ex sit amet, vulputate enim. Morbi varius arcu id tortor egestas ornare. Etiam porttitor et elit et condimentum. Maecenas libero felis, consequat varius pharetra non, tempor eget lacus. Fusce vel volutpat ante, vel feugiat nulla.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In maximus facilisis dolor, mollis consequat justo vestibulum in. Pellentesque ac laoreet turpis. Duis eget sodales elit. In eget eros vitae nibh laoreet viverra. Fusce tincidunt tortor id metus iaculis, in pulvinar urna consectetur. Nunc in leo non lacus volutpat rhoncus. Vestibulum aliquet tortor quis vehicula tempor. Vivamus faucibus orci nec condimentum consequat. Vestibulum vestibulum venenatis tincidunt. Donec non velit nulla. Nunc tellus est, feugiat quis interdum luctus, rhoncus non nisi. Aenean sagittis sed nisl sit amet vehicula. Nulla maximus at lacus eget tristique. Curabitur dignissim ligula et massa rhoncus, id lobortis odio dignissim. Sed ut dolor ac libero lacinia laoreet nec eu urna. Morbi justo lectus, ultrices ac tellus ut, lobortis semper risus.</p>

<p>Phasellus tempor dignissim odio, sodales vulputate metus facilisis sit amet. Maecenas vestibulum dapibus ipsum, nec bibendum neque tempor eget. Nunc ullamcorper, libero et semper condimentum, nibh mi pretium nisi, a hendrerit elit nunc sed metus. Duis lacinia quis dui ut interdum. In efficitur vitae magna sit amet aliquam. Pellentesque quis ullamcorper lorem. Etiam id ullamcorper velit. Suspendisse id tristique ante, suscipit facilisis nisl. Ut ac orci quis augue ornare egestas a id eros. Curabitur dictum eros mauris, lacinia vulputate diam dignissim at. Curabitur venenatis posuere lorem, non maximus lectus lobortis in.</p>

<p>Praesent in finibus purus. Maecenas nec rutrum mi. Donec molestie rhoncus ex vel laoreet. Duis id leo sit amet nisi tristique porta non at enim. Suspendisse eu pharetra lorem. Nunc posuere odio nisl, id iaculis felis fringilla ut. Proin aliquam sapien quis tortor vestibulum interdum. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Pellentesque gravida bibendum urna, tincidunt venenatis ligula egestas vitae. Fusce accumsan ligula et diam porta, id finibus felis vulputate.</p>

<p>Ut eleifend venenatis quam, vel ultricies diam vestibulum sit amet. Vestibulum accumsan eu felis et dictum. Cras turpis tellus, sodales ut nibh accumsan, rutrum ullamcorper ligula. Donec mollis sem eros, vitae finibus dui ullamcorper vel. Mauris sodales diam ut dictum mattis. Nam varius nisi ac efficitur dapibus. Nam dignissim, dolor at suscipit dignissim, ipsum eros mollis risus, eget facilisis lacus dolor id nisl. Vivamus dictum rutrum neque, vel accumsan lacus vulputate in. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris vel tortor sed mi faucibus egestas non maximus enim. Suspendisse sed mi sagittis, imperdiet felis sed, tristique nisi. Proin porta nisi at pretium volutpat. Quisque nec nisl dictum, dignissim erat sit amet, vestibulum dui.</p>

<p>Curabitur vitae consectetur felis. In quis ligula metus. Nunc mauris ex, viverra in suscipit in, ultricies id lorem. Sed ac libero at velit iaculis placerat vitae in odio. Sed tortor dui, lobortis nec pretium ut, ullamcorper a dui. Praesent congue erat sed ultrices pretium. Nullam consequat orci at ex aliquet, vitae aliquet lorem suscipit. Maecenas nisi purus, semper eu lorem vel, elementum dapibus quam. Suspendisse potenti. Nulla augue enim, vulputate a fringilla eget, sollicitudin nec turpis. Aenean vitae pulvinar ante. Nam ex dui, gravida a nunc sed, tristique lacinia sapien. Sed auctor laoreet nisl, et maximus risus. Fusce finibus bibendum mauris. Ut cursus euismod eros non dapibus. Sed luctus eleifend lorem venenatis aliquam.</p>

<p>Morbi volutpat velit vitae est molestie, nec porttitor orci tempus. Suspendisse lorem arcu, elementum sit amet diam sit amet, pharetra laoreet metus. Integer posuere sapien porta, placerat odio lobortis, sollicitudin augue. Integer mattis arcu est, gravida porta justo ultrices a. Etiam egestas in ante at interdum. Cras sodales at lectus nec interdum. Donec ac posuere ligula, id dictum lectus. Nullam et elit non nunc convallis pulvinar. Pellentesque vitae pulvinar ex. Etiam a mattis risus, vitae gravida neque.</p>

<p>Nullam vestibulum nisl a faucibus sodales. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla iaculis gravida sem at aliquam. Vestibulum id enim suscipit, condimentum ipsum ut, egestas libero. Proin et leo ac eros hendrerit tincidunt dapibus ac urna. Integer tincidunt, est et faucibus malesuada, purus ligula ultricies velit, quis rutrum lacus quam non neque. Sed facilisis ipsum eget nisl consectetur sollicitudin. Donec sodales massa non quam ornare tristique. Suspendisse condimentum dui dolor, in ultrices leo laoreet non.</p>

<p>Morbi mattis, mi nec fringilla dignissim, nisl risus pharetra massa, in luctus sem magna at ex. Nullam aliquam ultricies dolor, eget maximus eros auctor sed. Suspendisse sodales orci a elementum dignissim. Maecenas vulputate pharetra nisl vel cursus. Sed sit amet molestie lacus. Etiam fringilla maximus velit at posuere. Vestibulum non metus non sapien molestie tempor. Ut tincidunt faucibus lectus. Aliquam scelerisque ligula vel dictum fermentum. Donec egestas velit consequat vehicula condimentum. Etiam semper rhoncus efficitur. Ut ut leo pretium nisi pharetra pharetra. Nullam elementum, metus at sollicitudin convallis, mauris eros sagittis justo, quis venenatis ante magna dignissim nisl. Donec sit amet tempus tellus, id ultrices quam. Aliquam dui dolor, placerat non metus ut, mattis imperdiet nisi. Maecenas ultrices felis lacus, ut mattis ipsum laoreet vitae.</p>

<p>Fusce commodo faucibus volutpat. Nulla tristique libero at mi ultricies, scelerisque lobortis risus accumsan. Vestibulum iaculis, est a blandit eleifend, lorem justo porttitor arcu, a feugiat arcu magna eget nulla. Mauris posuere massa vitae diam pretium placerat nec ut ex. Ut porttitor nisi sit amet felis eleifend, non fermentum nibh placerat. In molestie mi a mi rutrum tempus. Praesent fringilla semper mi, at accumsan lorem lobortis euismod.</p>

<p>Fusce fermentum interdum leo non auctor. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Pellentesque lectus ante, vehicula ac blandit dictum, pulvinar non tortor. Ut faucibus erat luctus, convallis magna non, ornare dolor. Sed dictum, nunc non iaculis pharetra, mi nisl pretium libero, at tincidunt massa felis eu mauris. Maecenas sit amet lorem non enim finibus posuere. Ut pulvinar aliquam convallis. Maecenas eu purus nec tortor bibendum maximus in quis enim. Fusce vehicula leo non felis posuere aliquet. Nam aliquet mauris nec felis dictum, non semper diam efficitur. Duis blandit euismod vestibulum. Nulla quis leo venenatis, volutpat ex sit amet, vulputate enim. Morbi varius arcu id tortor egestas ornare. Etiam porttitor et elit et condimentum. Maecenas libero felis, consequat varius pharetra non, tempor eget lacus. Fusce vel volutpat ante, vel feugiat nulla.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In maximus facilisis dolor, mollis consequat justo vestibulum in. Pellentesque ac laoreet turpis. Duis eget sodales elit. In eget eros vitae nibh laoreet viverra. Fusce tincidunt tortor id metus iaculis, in pulvinar urna consectetur. Nunc in leo non lacus volutpat rhoncus. Vestibulum aliquet tortor quis vehicula tempor. Vivamus faucibus orci nec condimentum consequat. Vestibulum vestibulum venenatis tincidunt. Donec non velit nulla. Nunc tellus est, feugiat quis interdum luctus, rhoncus non nisi. Aenean sagittis sed nisl sit amet vehicula. Nulla maximus at lacus eget tristique. Curabitur dignissim ligula et massa rhoncus, id lobortis odio dignissim. Sed ut dolor ac libero lacinia laoreet nec eu urna. Morbi justo lectus, ultrices ac tellus ut, lobortis semper risus.</p>

<p>Phasellus tempor dignissim odio, sodales vulputate metus facilisis sit amet. Maecenas vestibulum dapibus ipsum, nec bibendum neque tempor eget. Nunc ullamcorper, libero et semper condimentum, nibh mi pretium nisi, a hendrerit elit nunc sed metus. Duis lacinia quis dui ut interdum. In efficitur vitae magna sit amet aliquam. Pellentesque quis ullamcorper lorem. Etiam id ullamcorper velit. Suspendisse id tristique ante, suscipit facilisis nisl. Ut ac orci quis augue ornare egestas a id eros. Curabitur dictum eros mauris, lacinia vulputate diam dignissim at. Curabitur venenatis posuere lorem, non maximus lectus lobortis in.</p>

<p>Praesent in finibus purus. Maecenas nec rutrum mi. Donec molestie rhoncus ex vel laoreet. Duis id leo sit amet nisi tristique porta non at enim. Suspendisse eu pharetra lorem. Nunc posuere odio nisl, id iaculis felis fringilla ut. Proin aliquam sapien quis tortor vestibulum interdum. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Pellentesque gravida bibendum urna, tincidunt venenatis ligula egestas vitae. Fusce accumsan ligula et diam porta, id finibus felis vulputate.</p>

<p>Ut eleifend venenatis quam, vel ultricies diam vestibulum sit amet. Vestibulum accumsan eu felis et dictum. Cras turpis tellus, sodales ut nibh accumsan, rutrum ullamcorper ligula. Donec mollis sem eros, vitae finibus dui ullamcorper vel. Mauris sodales diam ut dictum mattis. Nam varius nisi ac efficitur dapibus. Nam dignissim, dolor at suscipit dignissim, ipsum eros mollis risus, eget facilisis lacus dolor id nisl. Vivamus dictum rutrum neque, vel accumsan lacus vulputate in. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris vel tortor sed mi faucibus egestas non maximus enim. Suspendisse sed mi sagittis, imperdiet felis sed, tristique nisi. Proin porta nisi at pretium volutpat. Quisque nec nisl dictum, dignissim erat sit amet, vestibulum dui.</p>

<p>Curabitur vitae consectetur felis. In quis ligula metus. Nunc mauris ex, viverra in suscipit in, ultricies id lorem. Sed ac libero at velit iaculis placerat vitae in odio. Sed tortor dui, lobortis nec pretium ut, ullamcorper a dui. Praesent congue erat sed ultrices pretium. Nullam consequat orci at ex aliquet, vitae aliquet lorem suscipit. Maecenas nisi purus, semper eu lorem vel, elementum dapibus quam. Suspendisse potenti. Nulla augue enim, vulputate a fringilla eget, sollicitudin nec turpis. Aenean vitae pulvinar ante. Nam ex dui, gravida a nunc sed, tristique lacinia sapien. Sed auctor laoreet nisl, et maximus risus. Fusce finibus bibendum mauris. Ut cursus euismod eros non dapibus. Sed luctus eleifend lorem venenatis aliquam.</p>

<p>Morbi volutpat velit vitae est molestie, nec porttitor orci tempus. Suspendisse lorem arcu, elementum sit amet diam sit amet, pharetra laoreet metus. Integer posuere sapien porta, placerat odio lobortis, sollicitudin augue. Integer mattis arcu est, gravida porta justo ultrices a. Etiam egestas in ante at interdum. Cras sodales at lectus nec interdum. Donec ac posuere ligula, id dictum lectus. Nullam et elit non nunc convallis pulvinar. Pellentesque vitae pulvinar ex. Etiam a mattis risus, vitae gravida neque.</p>

<p>Nullam vestibulum nisl a faucibus sodales. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla iaculis gravida sem at aliquam. Vestibulum id enim suscipit, condimentum ipsum ut, egestas libero. Proin et leo ac eros hendrerit tincidunt dapibus ac urna. Integer tincidunt, est et faucibus malesuada, purus ligula ultricies velit, quis rutrum lacus quam non neque. Sed facilisis ipsum eget nisl consectetur sollicitudin. Donec sodales massa non quam ornare tristique. Suspendisse condimentum dui dolor, in ultrices leo laoreet non.</p>

<p>Morbi mattis, mi nec fringilla dignissim, nisl risus pharetra massa, in luctus sem magna at ex. Nullam aliquam ultricies dolor, eget maximus eros auctor sed. Suspendisse sodales orci a elementum dignissim. Maecenas vulputate pharetra nisl vel cursus. Sed sit amet molestie lacus. Etiam fringilla maximus velit at posuere. Vestibulum non metus non sapien molestie tempor. Ut tincidunt faucibus lectus. Aliquam scelerisque ligula vel dictum fermentum. Donec egestas velit consequat vehicula condimentum. Etiam semper rhoncus efficitur. Ut ut leo pretium nisi pharetra pharetra. Nullam elementum, metus at sollicitudin convallis, mauris eros sagittis justo, quis venenatis ante magna dignissim nisl. Donec sit amet tempus tellus, id ultrices quam. Aliquam dui dolor, placerat non metus ut, mattis imperdiet nisi. Maecenas ultrices felis lacus, ut mattis ipsum laoreet vitae.</p>

<p>Fusce commodo faucibus volutpat. Nulla tristique libero at mi ultricies, scelerisque lobortis risus accumsan. Vestibulum iaculis, est a blandit eleifend, lorem justo porttitor arcu, a feugiat arcu magna eget nulla. Mauris posuere massa vitae diam pretium placerat nec ut ex. Ut porttitor nisi sit amet felis eleifend, non fermentum nibh placerat. In molestie mi a mi rutrum tempus. Praesent fringilla semper mi, at accumsan lorem lobortis euismod.</p>

<p>Fusce fermentum interdum leo non auctor. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Pellentesque lectus ante, vehicula ac blandit dictum, pulvinar non tortor. Ut faucibus erat luctus, convallis magna non, ornare dolor. Sed dictum, nunc non iaculis pharetra, mi nisl pretium libero, at tincidunt massa felis eu mauris. Maecenas sit amet lorem non enim finibus posuere. Ut pulvinar aliquam convallis. Maecenas eu purus nec tortor bibendum maximus in quis enim. Fusce vehicula leo non felis posuere aliquet. Nam aliquet mauris nec felis dictum, non semper diam efficitur. Duis blandit euismod vestibulum. Nulla quis leo venenatis, volutpat ex sit amet, vulputate enim. Morbi varius arcu id tortor egestas ornare. Etiam porttitor et elit et condimentum. Maecenas libero felis, consequat varius pharetra non, tempor eget lacus. Fusce vel volutpat ante, vel feugiat nulla.</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me out! So I made some changes according to what you told me, but It is still firing when the page loads. If you want to, you view my entire web page here: https://jsfiddle.net/kupid/3usfeh7d/3/

Answer (score 0):

You need to change:

```
window.onscroll = myFunction();
```

Into

```
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};
```

Why? because the `onscroll` is an Event that executes a function after something had happened (Scroll Event in our case).
But when you use use the the code like `window.onscroll = myFunction();` the JS engine will immediately invoke the function regardless to the scroll event as soon as he sees this line of code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do two changes to achive what you are looking :

First as Shahar mentioned, you need to change the way you run the function  :

```
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};
```

And the other thing, you are using `getAttribute` method to update the value of your attribute, you need to use `setAttribute` instead :

```
div.setAttribute('data-percent', '100%');
```

And maybe add a height to your div with css to actually be able to scroll :

```
#div1{height:700px}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/odpzLtec/